# jQuery—Highlighting table rows in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm working on creating a tabular report of some information on a website. This table is fairly wide so I'd like to add a `4px` border to each row on hover using jQuery. Here is my script:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr').hover(function() {
        $(this).contents('td').css({'border-top':'4px solid #934739', 'border-bottom':'4px solid #934739'});
    },
    function() {
        $(this).contents('td').css({'border-top':'1px solid #000','border-bottom':'1px solid #000'});
    });
});
```

It works exactly as it should in Firefox. However, in Chrome it works fine for the first few rows but then it starts "leaving behind" some of the border color on previously hovered rows.

I'm on a Mac using Chrome 15.0.874.106. Here a jsFiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/D6eKE/1/

Is there anything I can do to make this work better in Chrome? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Very strange.  Seems to be in some way related to border-collapse.  If you don't collapse the borders it doesn't have the same issue:  http://jsfiddle.net/D6eKE/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're pretty close, so try adding the ID selector:

```
$(function(){
    $("#tableid tr").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
        },
        function(){
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        }
    );
});
```

You could also use the [columnHover](http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/columnhover/) plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tableid").columnHover({ hoverClass: "highlight" });
});
```

Lastly, you could also accomplish this with some simple CSS:

```
#tableid tr:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

Comment: I'd advise the last route, and if in jQuery use `addClass` and `removeClass` and then use css to style as opposed to `.css`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about `addClass` and `removeClass`. Does seem like a better option.

Comment: I think I'll go with `addClass` and `removeClass`. That seems much easier that what I was attempting to accomplish. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Don't forget you have access to `toggleClass` which can do both jobs at once.

Comment: @vecta Did changing to addClass and removeClass fix it?  I'm still seeing that same strange issue.

Comment: I've done the same thing with css.  instead of border, I change the background color, so I've never experienced artifacts of borders not redrawing properly. Great answer, though.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have to use the .each() to apply the function to all returned items by the jQuery selector $('tr'). This will iterate on the object array returned by jQuery and apply the desired action to each one of them, tr tag in this case.
Something like

```
$(function(){
    $('tr').hover(function() {
        $(this).css({'border-top':'4px solid #934739', 'border-bottom':'4px solid #934739'});
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css({'border-top':'1px solid #000', 'border-bottom':'1px solid #000'});
        });
});
```

Comment: There is no need for each here and the posted code doesn't work at all.  One of the strong points of jquery is that things apply to the whole collection and don't need to be iterated.

Comment: @Rynkadink: No, you do not _have_ to use `.each()`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, about .each().
@James Montagne, when leaving the 'td' it didn't work. Thanks for the minus. Code fully works now.

Comment: The code "works" in that it does something, but not what it is supposed to.  It is only highlighting individual cells, not the whole row.  And the `each` is still unneeded.  It also still has the issue described in the initial question.

Comment: Yea, fixed that. I've forgot the .content(); Thanks.